# How to understand the notation $(\Sigma \oplus l_{p_k})_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In the book "Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis" by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss I came across the following example:

**Example**
Let $E=(\Sigma \oplus l_{p_k})_2$. If $p_k\to \infty$, then the unit closed ball of $E$ is not an absolute neighbourhood uniform retract.

I would like to understand the example, but fail to understand even the symbol $(\Sigma \oplus l_{p_k})_2$ itself.

Could anyone please kindly explain what the space $E$ is?

Comment: Maybe this equivalent notation if more appealing to you: $\bigoplus_2\{ l_{p_k}: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. This is an $l_2$-sum of countably many Banach spaces $l_{p_k}$.

Comment: @Norbert Indeed it is far more appealing and clear, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E=\{(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\in \prod\limits_{k\in\mathbb N} \ell_{p_k}: \sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb N} \|x_k\|_{p_k}^2<\infty\}$.